# How do we tell what makes a good "where to find work" question

Tags: discussion, site-topic, vote-to-close

As we progress, we'll eventually start to see more of the same questions and will need to identify good close duplicates. The goal isn't to shut out the askers so much as it is to point them to existing answers. If those answers don't answer the asker's question, then he/she has an opportunity to edit and differentiate the question from the duplicate.

I did a search for "where to find work" and came up with a list of the following questions:

[Where can a new freelancer find people to work with?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/724/where-can-a-new-freelancer-find-people-to-work-with)

[How to find Web Development work outside the freelancing sites?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/how-to-find-web-development-work-outside-the-freelancing-sites)

[Where to find remote contract work in SAP / ABAP?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/742/where-to-find-remote-contract-work-in-sap-abap)

[How do I start my Freelancer career?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/695/how-do-i-start-my-freelancer-career)

[Where can a front end web developer start freelancing?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/719/where-can-a-front-end-web-developer-start-freelancing)

[How can I start freelancing and get online projects to work on?](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/707/issues-with-starting-freelancing)

[How to make the jump from normal employee to higher level freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/913/how-to-make-the-jump-from-normal-employee-to-higher-level-freelancing)

These are all great questions, but they're not expert level questions. They're all pretty much asking the same things, either how do I get started, or where can I find jobs. We've done a good job answering these so far, but it seems that we might want to put some things in place to prevent our site from being watered down with the same answers over and over again.

This stuff is on-topic, but it's probably time we start voting any more questions of this nature that come our way as duplicates, assuming the question matches one of the ones in this list.

If you have at least 500 reputation, you can help us reduce repetitive, duplicative content by identifying duplicates as they're posted and vote to close them. Additionally, those with 15 reputation or higher can flag duplicates. Identifying duplicate questions with answers will help prevent good information from being spread out across multiple posts and will link questions worded in slightly different ways to a single resource.